# Prevenir validación inicial IDataErrorInfo Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con WPF (usando Mvvm light toolkit)

Y me he topado con una problemática respecto a la validación de los formularios.

Para hacerlo, uso [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)  y una clase base muy sencilla

```
public abstract class ValidatableViewModelBase<T> : ViewModelBase, IValidatable<T>
    where T: ViewModelBase
{
    public string Error => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string this[string columnName] =>
        Validator.Validate(this as T, columnName).Errors.FirstOrDefault()?.ErrorMessage;
    public bool IsValid => Validator.Validate(this as T).IsValid;
    public abstract AbstractValidator<T> Validator { get; }
}
```

De tal manera, en cada ViewModel, simplemente sobrescribo la propiedad `Validator` por el validador correspondiente y todo funciona de manera perfecta!

Por ejemplo:

```
public class PlacaIram2250ViewModel : ValidatableViewModelBase<PlacaIram2250ViewModel>
{
    public double Potencia { get; set; }
    public override AbstractValidator<PlacaIram2250ViewModel> Validator { get; } = new PlacaIram2250ViewModelValidator();
}

public class PlacaIram2250ViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<PlacaIram2250ViewModel>
{
    public PlacaIram2250ViewModelValidator()
    {        
        RuleFor(x => x.Potencia).NotNull();        
    }
}
```

*Aclaro que cada ViewModel tiene aproximadamente 30 propiedades, las recorté a modo de ejemplo*

---

Como decía, el método de validación funciona perfectamente, el asunto es, que al cargar por primera vez la vista, el `TextBox` al que está bindeada la propiedad `Potencia` es validado, por lo que la ventana se muestra por primera vez con  el error de validación (un recuadro rojo en mi caso)

Vi algunas soluciones en SOen, pero siempre usando banderas para definir si una propiedad cambió o no (lo que no me es útil debido a que realizo toda la validación con [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/))

Mis `TextBox` los bindeo de la siguiente manera:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Potencia , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged , ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }"/>
```

¿Cuál es la manera de lidiar con esta problemática?

Comment: En el UpdateSourceTrigger has probado con el valor LostFocus?

Comment: @Xam Gracias por tu comentario!, pero sí, lo he intentado y el resultado es el mismo!